# Stanford IOS 7 assignment 2 - buttons don't flip over on reset click

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to IOS programming. Just started the Stanford IOS 7 course on iTunes.
I'm doing the second assignment. I've just implemented part 2. I've added a reset button, connected outlet to the controller, added action method that sets the game to nil and called the UIUpdate method. It seems that I've done everything right. I've debugged the code and I can see that the game is allocated and initialised again. And I can see the the buttonCards all have the background of backCover and an empty title.
But in the simulator the buttons are not flipped around for some reason. I'm sure that that's what is supposed to happen but I don't know why.

Can anyone explain me please?

Here is my controller code:

```
#import "CardGameViewController.h"
#import "PlayingCardDeck.h"
#import "CardMatchingGame.h"

@interface CardGameViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *cardButtons;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CardMatchingGame *game;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLable;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *resetbutton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segControlNumCardesMatched;
@end

@implementation CardGameViewController



- (CardMatchingGame *)game
{
    if (!_game)
    {
        _game = [[CardMatchingGame alloc] initWithCardCount:[self.cardButtons count]
                                                  usingDeck:self.createDeck];
    }

    return _game;
}

- (Deck *)createDeck
{
    return [[PlayingCardDeck alloc] init];
}


- (IBAction)touchResetButton:(id)sender
{
    [self updateUI];
}

- (IBAction)touchCardButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    int chosenButtonIndex = [self.cardButtons indexOfObject:sender];
    [self.game chooseCardAtIndex:chosenButtonIndex];
    [self updateUI];
}

- (void)updateUI
{
    for (UIButton *cardButton in self.cardButtons)
    {
        int cardButtonIndex = [self.cardButtons indexOfObject:cardButton]
        ;
        Card *card = [self.game cardAtIndex:cardButtonIndex];
        [cardButton setTitle:[self titleForCard:card] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cardButton setBackgroundImage:[self backgroundImageForCard:card] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cardButton.enabled = !card.isMatched;
        self.scoreLable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d", self.game.score];
    }
}

-(NSString *)titleForCard:(Card *)card
{
    return card.isChosen ? card.contents : @"";
}

- (UIImage *)backgroundImageForCard:(Card *)card
{
    return [UIImage imageNamed:card.isChosen ? @"cardFront" : @"cardBack"];
}

@end
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi.  Post some code from your view controller.  It will be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in the posted code? Try logging what you get back for `card.isChosen`.

Answer (score 1):

"added action method that sets the game to nil and called the UIUpdate method". I think what you mean is:

```
- (IBAction)touchResetButton:(id)sender
{
_game = nil;
[self game];
[self updateUI];
}
```

which is not in the above code. If you include this, then I don't see any problem with your controllers implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem since I don't know the project itself, but the UIControlState s you are trying to use might be wrong? I've had problems with that

The way you're doing it, you're only changing the image for UIControlStateNormal. Instead of having a function to change the image for that state, you could try setting default images for other states and then only changing state.
Since you're changing the state of the button, if it's disabled it wont change images to what you want since you're only changing the image for UIControlStateNormal

The problem might also be that it's supposed to be the button's image, not its background image, so you'd have to use `setImage`, not `setBackgroundImage`. It all depends on the project...

Comment: Then again all I said might be incorrect since I've also had problems with this recently :D